# Help with curb-fu gem - their documentation is light

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm using the curb-fu gem as my curl interface.  I'm trying to follow the grouptexting api for sending an sms message.

Here they give examples written in php:
http://grouptexting.com/sms-gateway/sms-api-docs.html

And I can get that to work just fine.

[curb-fu](https://github.com/gdi/curb-fu) has almost no documentation, and I can't quite seem to get things working properly.

Looking at the grouptexting api examples written in php, can anyone help me translate that into ruby/curb-fu?  Or, can someone point me to some more robust documentation for curb-fu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [README](https://github.com/gdi/curb-fu) contains several examples of using curb-fu. There's also a [YARD-generated API documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/curb-fu) available.

It seems pretty straightforward to use for me.

This PHP example

```
<?php
$ch=curl_init('https://app.grouptexting.com/api/sending');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"user=username&pass=userpassword&phonenumber= 2125551234&subject=test&message=test message");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
print($data); /* result of API call*/
?>
```

in Ruby + curb-fu translates into

```
response = CurbFu.post('https://app.grouptexting.com/api/sending', {
  :user => "username", :pass => "userpassword",
  :phonenumber => "2125551234", :subject => "test",
  :message => "test message"
})
puts response.body
```